# Redirect all to index and unable to get robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

This is my .htacces

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

All requests are sending to index and routing to correct PHP controller. How can I add exception to *robots.txt*.  At this moment google can't find file, because Router can't match route and returning 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rewrites:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/robots\.txt$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```